# Absolute positioning of navbar

Tags: html, css, css-position, menuitem, nav

Here I have a responsive navbar which I want to be absolute and menu items to float right but when I apply position property to it, menu items floats to left. Also applying absolute position to nav makes hamburger for small screen float left and when it opens the closing icon disappears.

Please help me figure out the right solution to make nav absolute but not affect the menu items and hamburger

> Note: While checking code snippet try it for both desktop and mobile screen

```js
    document.getElementById("hamburger").addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      document.querySelector(".mobile-menu").classList.toggle("active");
    });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  img {
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 80px;
  }
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Navigation Menu */

nav {
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

nav #menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

nav #menu li {
  padding: 0px 30px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

nav #menu li a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav #menu li a:hover {
  color: rgb(238, 215, 12);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav #menu {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Mobile Menu */

#hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 10px;
  top: 14px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburger .line {
  height: 5px;
  background: rgb(238, 215, 12);
  margin: 5px auto;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#hamburger.active #one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6px) translateY(6px);
}

#hamburger.active #two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburger.active #three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(10px) translateY(-12px);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #hamburger {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.mobile-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  display: table;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__items {
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__items li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__items li:hover {
  color: rgb(238, 215, 12);
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__items li:hover a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  color: rgb(238, 215, 12);
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__items li a {
  color: white;
}

.mobile-menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.99;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
}


/* Main */

h1 {
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation Menu -->
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="home"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="work">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="hamburger">
        <div class="line" id="one"></div>
        <div class="line" id="two"></div>
        <div class="line" id="three"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Mobile Menu -->
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <ul class="mobile-menu__items">
        <li><a href="home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="work">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Main -->
  <main>

    <h1>hello</h1>
  </main>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style to your css 
change menu ul li a

```
 nav ul li a{display:block;width:100%;float:right;text-align:right;}
```

Comment: Check here I tried what you suggested https://jsfiddle.net/j20csk6v/1/

Comment: What @S.nazari means is that you should not declare the "position" and "float" properties on the same selector. I.E., use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: yeah. when you declare the "position" to absolute then float dont work